# How do I create a scrapy TextResponse object from html?

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm sending a POST request to an API using `scrapy.FormRequest` and receiving a `TextResponse` object back. The body of this object looks like so:

```
{
"Refiners": ...
"Results": ...
}
```

I am only interested in the `Results` portion of the response as it contains HTML that I would like to parse.

As such, I am trying to creating a new `TextResponse` object containing only the `Results` portion in the body, so that I am able to use the `response.css` method on it.

I tried the following and it yielded an empty response body. Any thoughts on why and how to fix this?

```
new_response = scrapy.http.TextResponse(response.json()["Results"])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `HTMLResponse` class and you need to provide the `body` and `encoding` arguments in the constructor.

```py
from scrapy.http import HtmlResponse
new_response = HtmlResponse(url="some_url", body=response.json()["Results"], encoding="utf-8")
```

You can then use `new_response.css(...)` to select elements.